# Remove leading and trailing spaces from drawing.xml

Tags: excel, xlsx, docx4j

Is there any way to remove leading and trailing spaces from drawing.xml ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide more information about your problem?

I guess you will need to loop over your XML nodes and doing the `trim()` method on them.